# Can Hive VARCHAR fields store unicode characters?

Tags: oracle, hadoop, unicode, parquet, orc

I read the FAQ and according to [this section](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/User+FAQ#UserFAQ-DoesHivesupportUnicode?), Hive obviously supports Unicode. But I can't tell what datatype field in a Hive table allows for Unicode characters; is it `VARCHAR` or `STRING`? I can't find any answers online and am unable to test either yet.

I'm most likely going to use ORC or Parquet, do both support Unicode-compatible fields? The data is coming from a `NVARCHAR` field in an Oracle source

Comment: Nowadays data type VARCHAR2 support unicode, since default character set is al32utf8.

Comment: Not following. I know `VARCHAR2` in Oracle supports Unicode. So what would be an appropriate column in Hive that supports Unicode as well?

Comment: I mean usually there is no need to use NVARCHAR2 datatype. VARCHAR2 is sufficient.

Comment: Well the NVARCHAR2 already exists. That's not something I can change unfortunately.